# I want to overloaded operator<<, and get cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I want to overloaded operator << , and get this error.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.cpp    In function 'int main()':
22  18  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.cpp    [Error] cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
39  0   D:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream
1       C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.cpp                     from C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.cpp
602 5   D:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ostream [Note] initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = OutputFormatter]'
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 
class OutputFormatter {
public:
    OutputFormatter(int width) : m_width(width) {}

    template<typename T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const OutputFormatter& formatter) {
        os << std::setw(formatter.m_width);
        return os;
    }

private:
    int m_width;
};

OutputFormatter formatted_output(8); 

int main() {
    int a = 123, b = 456;
    std::cout << formatted_output << a << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

tested using tdm-gcc-4.9.2 with -std=c++11

I was hoping to overload operator << to make all output variables 8 characters wide, but it doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: Dare I ask why you're templating that operator? Fyi, "I get an error" isn't helpful. "I get **this** error: " and showing the error message verbatim is considerably more informative.

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question. The one i get here is pretty clear about whats wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/4ncvPeWPa You seem to have picked randomly part of the message but not the first error

Comment: It is impossible for the compiler to deduce a type for the (pointless) template argument. The error message is confusing because your compiler is really old.

Comment: no matter what gcc version I tried, I always got similar error message that is different from the one you report in the title. Either you are not showing us the code you compiled or you misread the error message  or something else weird is going on. In any case you should include the error message in the question. If it is too long, take the first part. The output from your compiler contains the line of the error, the code where the error appears and more valuable information. The fragment you included in the title is not very useful.

Comment: OK, thank for all of yours advices, it's my first time ask question there.

Comment: well ok, the error message is still weird. However, that aside, the problem with the code is that your `<<` is a template. Its not clear why you made it a template. Unless you explain that, the answer is just to not make it a template.

Comment: I did need to delete the template indeed. I was hoping to  overload operator << to make all output variables 8 characters wide, but it doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: its not clear what your aim was. you can use `std::setw` directly. DId you want to have the width to be sticky? SHould it apply for `a` and for `b` ? That would be a different quesiton you can ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: yes, i  want to have the width to be sticky and make it apply for a and for b. I don't want to type std::setw so many times XD

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<<` doesn't participate in overload resolution because you define a template argument (that isn't used). So this will do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 
class OutputFormatter {
public:
    OutputFormatter(int width) : m_width(width) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const OutputFormatter& formatter) {
        os << std::setw(formatter.m_width);
        return os;
    }

private:
    int m_width;
};

OutputFormatter formatted_output(8); 

int main() {
    int a = 123, b = 456;
    std::cout << formatted_output << a << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the immediate effect [on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xcvcdG4Tv).